# React элемент не видит Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, redux

Пишу тестовое приложение на React, мой компонент не видит store переданный через провайдер

```
import './secret.css'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import login from '../../actions/actions';

const Secret = ({ store }) => {
    console.log(store.getState())
    return (
        <div className="secret" >
            <h1 className="secret__title-nologin">You are not logined</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLogin: state.isLogin,
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = { login }


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Secret);
```

Мой индекс, который по идеи должен передать store всему проекту

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import store from '../../login-app/src/store'

import App from './components/app';

console.log('index.js');
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter >
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider >
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

мой reduser

```
const initialState = {
    isLogin: false

};

const reduser = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'USER_LOGIN':
            return {
                isLogin: true
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default reduser;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы подписались через `mapStateToProps` на ключ `isLogin` вот его и выводите в консоль

```
const Secret = ({ isLogin}) => {
    console.log(isLogin)
    return (
        <div className="secret" >
            <h1 className="secret__title-nologin">You are not logined</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Если хотите получить весь `store`, то `mapStateToProps`  перепишите вот так:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        state: state,
    }
}
```

и выводите в консоль:

```
const Secret = ({ state}) => {
    console.log(state) // getState() не нужен
    return (
        <div className="secret" >
            <h1 className="secret__title-nologin">You are not logined</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, только начинаю осваивать React, сидел с этим весь день.